# What Javascript library to use with Laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, zend-framework, laravel-4

I am creating a schedule/employee management application. My first iteration was in Zend Fraemwork and jQuery was used for the client-side. Now I am moving to Laravel, and was wondering if I should change the JavaScript as well.

Basically, you create a schedule, create shifts, create tasks within that shift. Move/drag/resize tasks, drag tasks from shift-to-shift.

What is the best JavaScript solution for me? Is Angular JS too much? I've heard it is quite nice at handling binding and writing to to DB, and since I would be making many AJAX calls, it might make the application smoother and faster. But is it easy to manipulate DOM (like the drag and resize) as easily as jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use AngularJs and make some directives for jQuery Intergration.

jQuery is great for DOM manipulation but not for making application. AngularJs does. However, Angular is more complicated than jQuery that you might not be able to catch up as quick as jQuery.

BTW, no matter what framework you use in backend is not quite matter for frontend

Comment: Okay, so then use Laravel for the backend, Angular for the frontend, and jQuery for any DOM manipulation that is needed?

Comment: Yes. When you learn more about AngularJs you will love it. But it is not that easy. Work hard!

Comment: Haha, I'm both scared and excited!! Thanks

Comment: egghead.io has lots of great videos.